# selecting classes in jQuery

Tags: jquery

I am doing learn jQuery on codeschool.com and one problem troubled me. 
We are learning to select multiple html elements within a single jQuery entry. The html code used is below and we are supposed to select the elements of the asian class and those of the sale class.

The correct answer is $(".asian, .sale")

My question is, how did ".sale" become the class's name? If you look in the html below you will see that there is no element with a "class=sale", just an element with a class = "europe sale"." Why is the jQuery calling for ".sale" and  not ".europe sale"?

```
<div id="tours-wrapper">
  <h1>Guided Tours</h1>
  <ul id="tours">
    <li class="america">
      <h2>New York, New York</h2>
      <span class="details">$1,899 for 7 nights</span>
      <ul class="vote"><li><a href="#">↑</a></li><li><a href="#">↓</a></li></ul>
    </li>
    <li class="europe sale">
      <h2>Paris, France</h2>
      <span class="details">$2,499 for 7 nights</span>
      <ul class="vote"><li><a href="#">↑</a></li><li><a href="#">↓</a></li></ul>
    </li>
    <li class="europe">
      <h2>Madrid, Spain</h2>
      <span class="details">$1,577 for 5 nights</span>
      <ul class="vote"><li><a href="#">↑</a></li><li><a href="#">↓</a></li></ul>
    </li>
    <li class="asia">
      <h2>Tokyo, Japan</h2>
      <span class="details">$1,999 for 5 nights</span>
      <ul class="vote"><li><a href="#">↑</a></li><li><a href="#">↓</a></li></ul>
    </li>
  </ul>

  <ul class="sorting">
    <li><a href="#">America</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Europe</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Asia</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: The `class` attribute holds a *space-separated* list of class names.

Comment: I think it is a typo in tutorial, they seem to want: `$(".asia, .sale")` which means all elements with class asia **OR** sale. If you want only elements (here one) with class europe **AND** sale, use that: `$(".europe.sale")`. `$(".sale.europe")` would return same result

Answer (score 2):

Class `europe sale` is like two class `europe` and another `sale` you can select each class or `europe` or `sale` but take always the element with class `europe sale`

To select your eleement with two class `europe sale` you can do more ways for example:

```
$('.europe')
```

or

```
$('.sale')
```

you select the element because the class is contained in that array of class

To take only the element with class `europe sale` you can do:

```
$('.europe.sale')
```

Comment: I think it should be mentioned that it could also be selected with `.europe.sale` which will only select elements with both classes

Answer (score 2):

Classes in html are separated by space. So if you set "europe sale", then both are considered as the element's classes.

Answer (score 1):

Basically there are two classes in `<li class="europe sale">`. One is europe  and second is sale.

Answer (score 0):

More classes can be applied to one HTML element. they are space separated.

Answer (score 0):

As the class attribute contains a space character, there are actually 2 classes being associated with that element, `.europe` and `.sale`.

Answer (score 0):

Each words in class attribute are class. 
europe - is the first class that used, and sale is the second class.

Answer (score 0):

Classes can be defined multiple times. In your stylesheet there is two classes, one is europe and another is sale, even if you want there you can specify more classes with a space. Now in your jquery you are selecting that one class sale. If you want to select sale class which contains europe class then you can select as this `$('.europe.sale')`

Answer (score 0):

CSS allows for multiple class names within a single element. That means that your `li` element has both classes `europe` and `sale`.

[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=HTML/Global_attributes#attr-class) says :

**class**: 
This attribute is a space-separated list of the classes of the element. Classes allows CSS and Javascript to select and access specific elements via the class selectors or functions like the DOM method document.getElementsByClassName.

Answer (score 0):

From the [HTML4 specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/global.html#h-7.5.2) (emphasis mine):

> **class = [cdata-list](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/types.html#type-cdata) [[CS]](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/types.html#case-sensitive)**
>       This attribute assigns a class name or set of class names to an element. Any number of elements may be assigned the same class name or
>   names. **Multiple class names must be separated by white space
>   characters.**

Hence, if an element has the attribute `class="europe sale"`, it means that it has two classes: `europe` and `sale`.